# Why didn't Frodo tell the others that Boromir would try to take the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In the movie *LOTR: The Fellowship of the Ring,* I am wondering why Frodo didn't tell Aragorn, or one of the others in the fellowship, that Galadriel had told him that Boromir would try to take the One Ring. I would think that Frodo would want them to know this so that they could keep a constant watch over him while the group traveled on to Mordor.

Why didn't Frodo tell the others that Boromir would try to take the One Ring?

Comment: Because Peter Jackson made it up for dramatic effect. In the book, this is all that is said of what she got from Boromir: *I should have said that she was tempting us, and offering what she pretended to have the power to give. It need not be said that I refused to listen. The Men of Minas Tirith are true to their word.’ But what he thought that the Lady had offered him Boromir did not tell.* Boromir says something that makes Frodo suspicious after they leave, but nothing even close to concrete.

Comment: If you were OK with a book answer, I can make that (with some extra detail) an answer, but I'm assuming you want a movie answer.

Comment: @Shamshiel, well, I based my question off of the movie version of events, so yes, I guess I'm looking for an answer based off of the movie. It doesn't seem logical to me that Frodo would want to keep this information secret especially since it could mean that Boromir may harm him or even kill him in order to get the One Ring.

Comment: Does Galadriel tell Frodo that Boromir will try take the ring, or that unspecified "he" will? Without clarification, it could have been almost anyone in the fellowship, if Frodo was paranoid enough, though the two obvious candidates are Aragorn and Boromir. Even in the movie, Frodo isn't sure Aragorn won't try to take the ring, when they meet at the top of Amon Hen, _after_ Boromir had tried to take it.

Comment: Peter Jackson's logic: Do whatever looks cool on screen, let SFF Stack Exchange users write it for you afterwards.

Comment: Because Movie!Frodo lacks the agency and character building that Frodo does in the book, and is written as being largely helpless. Even at the end, in Sammath Naur, Frodo in the book is much more emphatic and decisive in claiming the Ring. (If you've not read the book, here's a something you might find interesting: Frodo tells Gollum he would use the influence of the Ring to force him (Gollum) to kill himself, not something you can imagine Elijah Wood saying!)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Because the Ring didn’t want him to

In both the movies and the books it is clear that the Ring is semi-sentient and has “wants”: the primary one being that it wants to return to Sauron. Or, perhaps more accurately, it responds to Sauron’s desire to regain it. More speculatively, it “wants” to be wielded by someone with the power to do so.

Boromir was more likely to fulfil both “wants” than Frodo. The Ring has a history of discarding bearers when they no longer suit it. It abandoned both Isuldur and Gollum - it might have been waiting for an opportunity to abandon Frodo. Indeed, it had already done so in the Misty Mountains, slipping free of Frodo right in the path of Boromir.

Also, the ring makes its bearer bat-shit crazy and paranoid.

Comment: The movies dramatically overplayed the sentience and allure of the Ring, but I suppose this is a good movie answer.

Comment: @Shamshiel well, yeah

Comment: The Ring is absolutely not sentient. Its "actions" are merely manifestations of the magic it has been imbued with, in order to attempt to comply with the will of its creator.

Comment: Isn't the ring slipping free in the path of Boromir in the Misty Moutains made up by Peter Jackson too? I don't remember this from the books..

Comment: Perhaps "sapient" is more accurate than "sentient"?

Comment: @IanKemp This answer just says that "the Ring is *semi*-sentient". Just semi. And I think it's fitting. Gandalf says "A Ring of Power looks after itself" and "It was not Gollum, Frodo, but the Ring itself that decided things".

Comment: @Fabio I've always wanted to ask if the Ring "wanted" to be destroyed.   Several of the key links on the path to its destruction were caused by its own effects.

Comment: @Spencer Well, the ring does have adversaries. Maybe it just can't handle the complex multi-step planning required to prevent the fellowship from turning its own actions against it. Plus, there are plenty of examples of humans making decisions that turn out to backfire on them, sometimes spectacularly, so it's not a stretch to see how a semi-sentient (or sapient or whatever) magical object could do the same.

Comment: I think you make a good point that the One Ring had tried to make Boromir its new owner when it slipped free of Frodo and Boromir then picked it up from the snow covered ground.

Answer (score 11):

#### Because it's intentionally ambiguous in the film

Galadriel only says "he", not "Boromir".

Does Boromir want it? Sure, we've seen that when the Ring "falls" into the snow in the Misty Mountains.

How about Aragorn though? The reason the scene with Frodo and Aragorn at the Breaking of the Fellowship is so powerful is because up to that point *we don't know*. Up to that point, Boromir has always been the one who's been closer to the hobbits (especially Merry and Pippin), and Aragorn has been quite standoffish with them. He's been a good leader, but not necessarily likeable. We also know that Aragorn is afraid he'll be tempted the same way his great-however-many-grandfather was - so not only do we not know, but the character doesn't know either.

The story of the Fellowship film isn't just character development for the hobbits. Jackson also managed to build in character development for Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli, something which is famously absent from the book. Remember that the book itself was a loving pastiche of Norse sagas. Jackson knew that he had to produce something which would stand up to modern standards of story-telling.  Aragorn facing down that temptation is the point where he rises to be better than Isildur.  Everything afterwards is detail - exciting detail, to be sure, but closing Frodo's hand back over the Ring is when he earns the right to be king, and Boromir says as much as he dies.

And the "he" could also be Sam, or even Merry or Pippin. Frodo is already getting the effects of the Ring by that point. Pippin proves his own weakness later with the palantir, after all. Sam has to virtually drown to prove himself to Frodo.

There's no shortage of "he"s, basically.

Comment: Not to mention S and S.

Comment: @Spencer Sauron, sure, but that wouldn't exactly be a secret.  And Frodo hasn't met (and doesn't meet) Saruman.  If we granted Galadriel greater precognitive powers then it could also include Faramir (that's another good change in the film, because it never made any sense that Faramir was somehow immune to the effects of the Ring).  But she does then say "you know of whom I speak", and Frodo hasn't met Faramir at that point.

Comment: We can argue the semantics of that, but yours is the right answer anyway.

Comment: Faramir isn't "immune" to the ring (even Gandalf isn't by his own admission); Faramir is actually just stronger in character than Boromir. This is quite clear in the books. Relevant to the question because no, Faramir is not a good candidate for the "he".

Answer (score 7):

Frodo tries to see the best in people; when Boromir then acts on it, Frodo again allows him a final dignity of silence.